# Being too hospitable to guests?

Tags: sharia

I have a question regarding the treatment of guests in Islam. I know that the Prophet (PBUH) taught us to be caring and hospitable to guests and to treat them kindly. But sometimes when me and my husband go to visit others they make us feel uncomfortable, perhaps not even really knowing that they are doing so. A lot of times, and I think this may have to do more with the Arab culture than Islam, they try to impose on us to stay longer very late into the night or even to sleep over, which makes me and my husband very uncomfortable. Is it alright, from a religious perspective, to insist on such things on your guests? If your guests refuse and make it clear that they cannot sleep over or stay late, is it right to keep insisting that they do? Is it possible to take hospitality too far?

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you look at the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq) in it is what you need to know about how things work here.  We are looking forward to having you as an active participant here.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this all has to do with Arab and some other cultures. People tend to show their hospitality and respect by sticking to their guns. Simply turning down their offer might be considered disrespectful or even downright rude. I would try to get used to their culture and not try to offend them. You could say that you really appreciate their offer but you really have to go because you have other plans and arrangements.

Comment: Sifting through some webpages, I couldn't find a single source where this kind of action could be considered Islamic. That said, being respectful to one's guest is considered an Islamic duty.

Answer (score 1):

Noah ([in comments above](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/being-too-hospitable-to-guests#comment14961_7459)) provided an excellent explanation.

If your hosts are insisting you to stay late or sleepover, it is because they are showing hospitality. They have enjoyed your company and want to continue that.

I completely understand this sort of behavior (as I go through this many times). You cannot always fulfill your hosts' wishes to stay longer. In such case, you can politely turn down their (repeated) requests. Being rude isn't a nice thing though.

In case you encounter such behavior a lot, you can be preemptive and set your hosts' expectations before getting there that you cannot only stay for X hours or days etc., and have to get back as you have other commitments.

Islam, undoubtedly, teaches one to be nice to guests. If a host is insisting a guest to stay longer, then the guest should not be rude or loose temper. That is certainly not what Islam wants Muslims to do.

If you have something to do after work but your boss wants you to stay late, how will you tackle that situation?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is NO. As I know islam never ask people to insist on such a thing. Islam said respect your guests and let them be comfortable. So as these, it is not acceptable to insist on such things on your guests.

Answer (score -1):

It is just a way to show their hospitality and that they welcome you without limit but it is culture based as the main point to make your guest comfortable and this does not opposite the wiliness to show hospitality

Actually this is called in Arabic Al-Karam or in English Generosity and it is different than hospitality.